# Change Font Style in Any Cell with Background Color Other than White

Tags: excel, vba, colors, format

In Excel, is it possible to change the font style of any cell with a background color other than white (or no fill) though a macro? I would like this to apply to an entire worksheet (all cells in a single tab; not the entire workbook).

Example:

Select: all cells in current worksheet with background color other than white (or no fill)

Change: font style (in selected cells only) to white, bold, no underline

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes, it is possible". You will probably need VBA for this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if that would help you out!

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        If .Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Or .Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```